# Eight words: which one is different?

Tags: pattern, language

These eight words all have something in common, but one is slightly different. Which one?

- broad
- corn
- gain
- jar
- like
- mount
- range
- side

To clarify, seven of these words have a specific property in common, which is shared by very few other words. The eighth word has a similar (and also fairly rare) characteristic but is slightly different.

Comment: You really need to add something a little more specific, because any "identify the odd one out" without further information just becomes "find a reason for any word you choose to be considered the odd one out" and everyone just has to guess what you're thinking.

Comment: @GlenO I clarified.

Comment: Great puzzle, with an answer that's clearly correct once discovered.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer is **Range**

Why?

> You can place the letter "a" in front of each word to get a new word. Abroad, Acorn, Again, Ajar, Alike, Amount, Aside. The word "range" requires an extra letter to make it work, Arrange.

Comment: I was going to answer this after I saw it in the close-vote queue, but you beat me to it. Good job!

Answer (score 9):

The answer is BROAD.   Each of the other words can be used as a verb.  However BROAD is widely used as an adjective ----- but not a verb. That is a distinct characteristic.

Cheers, everybody!  My first time on the site!

Zephyr

Comment: I like this answer, but “corn” as a verb is exceedingly rare.

Comment: Maybe not so rare! To corn beef is to marinate in brine. Who hasn't had 'corned beef'? Yum. Now I am hungry.

Comment: This is a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **jar**. All of the words have at least three letters, but "jar" is the only one with just three.

Comment: That doesn't seem like rare characteristic

Comment: @Zikato - the "rare characteristic" line was added after Ian posted his answer.

Comment: @Zikato: moving target puzzles are so difficult to solve!